# What is the font used by the John C Winston company?

Tags: font

In the 1950s the John C. Winston publishing company used a distinctive font for the cover titles and chapter headings of their various novels (including their sci-fi novels).

I know the style is '*sweeping*' (or '*slanted*'), but is there a specific name for this font?

---

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s not seeking for a SFF answer.

Comment: We’ve answered font identification questions before, I don’t see why this wouldn’t be on-topic. An image of the font in question would help though

Comment: @fez - They weren't all scifi novels, but if OP can identify at least one, then that makes it on-topic

Comment: It's worth noting that in the 1950s font were often custom-designed for publishers.

Comment: Here's an example: https://www.gutenberg.org/files/33644/33644-h/images/title.jpg & https://www.gutenberg.org/files/33644/33644-h/images/cover.jpg

Comment: The Graphic Design stack permits font ID questions, but you are expected to use automatic identification services first https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info

Comment: The smaller Sans Serif looks like it could be Futura.

Comment: @MarkRansom: It's definitely some Futura-inspired geometric sans serif font, but to my eye it lacks the distinctive low x-height of Futura itself. It might be [Twentieth Century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twentieth_Century_(typeface)), which has very similar letter shapes to Futura but slightly different proportions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [What the Font?](https://www.myfonts.com/pages/whatthefont) site identifies it as *Lydian Cursive*:

[image: Lydian]

Whether it's actually Lydian or a copy done in house I can't tell, but it's certainly very close.

Comment: Here's a sample of Lydian Cursive: http://www.identifont.com/find?font=lydian+cursive&q=Go That distinctive uppercase Y matches other Winston titles I've seen.

Comment: Eg, The Year When Stardust Fell https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/14/The-Year-When-Stardust-Fell.jpg

Comment: @PM2Ring ... Wait.  Lydian Cursive is from 1991?

Comment: @GEdgar That date is probably for the particular digitised form on that page. The Lydian font family actually has [its own, brief, Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lydian_(typeface)), which lists the Cursive variant as introduced in 1940, although without a direct reference.

Comment: @GEdgar when you're trying to build your library of digital fonts, what are you more likely to do - start new fonts from scratch, or digitize your vast existing catalog?

Comment: @MarkRansom I think in the 1980s and 1990s, it was often a case of "if you're transitioning to fully digital typesetting and printing, how do you retain the same typefaces you've built your brand on, or have displayed in places you're not replacing?" My brother worked for a company specialising in exactly that; I seem to remember him working on one used on the destination boards of London buses.